# Como verificar se um select já possui uma opção selecionada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Tenho uma página onde existe alguns selects (representando as funções dos usuários, nos quais podem ser: Líder, Participante ou Para Conhecimento).

Existe algumas regras de negócio:

1- **Se o usuário for selecionado como LÍDER, ele não poderá ter mais nenhuma outra função**, apenas deverá ter uma (*Líder*);

2 - **Não deverá conter mais de um líder**. Por exemplo, tenho uma lista com 3 usuários e seleciono um deles como LÍDER, nos outros selects a opção LÍDER deverá ser desabilitada, pois só é permitido apenas um único usuário ser o Líder;

Eu já consegui fazer essa validação nos selects já existentes na página, porém tem a opção de adicionar mais usuários na lista. E é aí que minha validação não funciona, pois se eu já estiver com um usuário **LÍDER** (selecionado) e querer adicionar mais um usuário na minha lista, o select desse novo usuário (que é adicionado de forma dinâmica via JS) deveria já vir com a opção *LÍDER* **desabilitada**, pois na minha lista (antes de adicionar esse novo usuário) já havia um usuário Líder.

Como fazer uma verificação das opções selecionadas, para que a validação funcione também nos novos usuários que são adicionados dinamicamente?

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/4a0r6cwb/

Aqui está um exemplo do meu código JS que adiciona o select dinâmico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá,
Poderia mostrar como você esta fazendo?

Comment: André, como estás a acrescentar esse novo `select`?  Estás a clonar ou a adicionar uma _string_ de HTML?

Comment: É por string, @Sergio

Comment: Podes juntar à pergunta o código que insere esse novo select?

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando a imagem de como eu estou fazendo para adicionar o novo select, @Sergio

Comment: Acredito que precisaria apenas criar um método que verificasse os options selecionados, e se Líder estiver selecionado já em algum select, o novo select seria adicionado e automaticamente a opção Líder dele seria desabilitada... Mas não estou sabendo como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

É so executar

```
   $('select').change();
```

depois de terminar de adicionar o novo select.

forçando ele a executar um change e assim chamando todo fluxo de verificação

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Eu tentei de outra forma: https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/5t8noxne/2/

Agora eu só precisava que ele desabilite apenas quando for selecionado o Líder, e não nas outras duas opções (Participante e Para Conhecimento)... você pode me ajudar?